# Simplify your answer completely: $5i(1 + i)^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Simplify your answer completely: $5i(1 + i)^2$

I know the answer is $-10$, but I don't know how to get it. Things I tried:

foiling $(1+i)^2$ and then distributing $5i$.

distributing $5i$ into $(1+i)$ and then foiling

Comment: When you tried those things, what did you get and how did you get it?

Comment: Your approach should work. We have $(1+i)^2=1+2i+i^2=2i$.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason  I wrote it down wrong as (1+i)(1-i)

Comment: common mistake when your thinking is one step ahead of your writing

Comment: ''Foiling''? I've never heard the term before.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva "First outer inner last", referring to the pairs of terms you multiply when expanding a product of two binomials. I don't particularly like it but it seems to be popular in elementary algebra instruction nowadays.

Comment: @DavidK lol  I grew up learning "FOIL IT!".

Comment: @DavidK : I learned my elementary algebra in French, which probably explains why I never heard the term before... but it sounds silly. The term "expand" still does the trick for me.. anyway thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2,$$ one has$$5i(1+i)^2=5i(1^2+2\cdot 1\cdot i+i^2)=5i(1+2i-1)=5i\cdot 2i=-10.$$

Answer (score 3):

Foiling first is the correct path to take, so once expanded, you can then multiply by $5i$. To foil, remember: $$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$ That works for real *and* non-real numbers, $a, b$.

$$5i[(1+i)^2]=5i(1+2i+i^2)=5i(1+2i -1) =5i\cdot 2i = 10\cdot i^2 = -10$$

Answer (score 1):

$$5i(1 + i)^2=$$
$$5i(1+i)(1+i)=$$
$$(\left|5i\right|e^{arg(5i)i})(\left|1+i\right|e^{arg(1+i)i})(\left|1+i\right|e^{arg(1+i)i})=$$
$$\left(5e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}\right)\left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}\right)\left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}\right)=$$
$$\left(5e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}\right)\left(2e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}\right)=$$
$$10e^{\pi i}=$$
$$10\left(\cos(\pi)+\sin(\pi)i\right)=$$
$$10(-1+0i)=$$
$$-10$$

Answer (score 0):

$\arg (1+i) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\arg (i) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, therefore $\arg(5i(1 + i)^2) = \arg(i) + 2\arg(1+i) =  \pi$.

Then $|1+i| = \sqrt{2}$, $|5i|=5$, so $|5i(1+i)^2|=|5i|\,|1+i|^2 = 10$.

Together you will have $5i(1 + i)^2 = 10\angle \pi = -10$.

I think in this way it is easier to visualize.

Comment: The best for visualization, but I think the straightforward algebraic method is best for computation.